# How to add validation and duplicate record check w.r.t. to latest record using $.validator.addMethod bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-validate, bootstrap-modal

Following code is for validation but for the same I want to check latest is duplicate or not, if yes then give error message of saying record is already present.

```
$.validator.addMethod("region_name", function(value) {            
     if (value.trim().length >=2){
     return value;
     } 
    }, 'At least two charachters Enter Region');  
    validator = $('#region_form').validate({
                rules:{
                    region_name:{
                        required: true,
                        region_name: true//this is for error msg which we write in addMethod
                    }           
                },                    
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorClass: 'help-block',
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    if(element.parent('.input-group').length) {
                        error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                    } else {
                        error.insertAfter(element);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [remote method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/) to check input value against database

```
rules:{
    region_name:{
        required: true,
        region_name: true,//this is for error msg which we write in addMethod
            remote: {
            url: "check.php",
            type: "post"
            }
    }
},
messages: {
    region_name: {
        remote: "Define Remote Validation Message Here"
    }
},
```

And you don't need to write custom method `.addMethod` to check the length of value in input, it can also be done as follow

```
rules:{
    region_name:{
        required: true,
        minlength: 2 //Minimum 2 charachters required
    }
},
```

[Reference](http://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply but I need client side check and compare for duplicates. Can we do that?